# Does the adjoin Operation in SBCL Always Involve a Search?

Tags: set, common-lisp, sbcl

The Common Lisp Hyperspec gives the following equivalence for the [`adjoin`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/f_adjoin.htm) function on a set:

```
(adjoin item list :key fn)
   ==  (if (member (fn item) list :key fn) list (cons item list))
```

But does this mean an implementation, in particular SBCL, necessarily searches the corresponding list for the item? I'm wondering about simply using `adjoin` as a test for set membership, but only if the implementation automatically represents certain sets efficiently as a hashtable, bit vector, etc, allowing lookup instead of search.

```
(if (eq (adjoin item set) set)
  'item-present
  'item-absent)
```

I have the same question about how `alexandria:setp` is implemented. Of course, the other option is to appropriately represent the set myself, but I'd like to take advantage of the internal SBCL or alexandria optimizations if feasible.

Comment: Lists aren't automatically indexed, so I don't see any way that `adjoin` can avoid searching.

Comment: If you want efficient searching, use a `HASHTABLE`

Comment: alexandria:setp -> https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/alexandria/alexandria/-/blob/master/alexandria-1/lists.lisp#L314

Comment: @Barmar, I also need to maintain the set as a vector to access elements by position, so adding a hashtable is some duplication, unless there's an interesting way to combine the advantages of each.

Comment: Use `sycamore` or `FSet` to have proper set implementations, the ones in the standard are "set operations on lists" so they need to satisfy both the set interface and the list interface, which makes it hard to implement efficiently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to verify by suitable use of meta-. that neither SBCL's `adjoin` nor alexandria's `setp` do any deep magic.  As Barmar points out in a comment it's almost inconceivable that they should.

However if you want a test for set membership of sets represented as lists, there is one: it's called `member`.  It, also, won't do any magic.

Comment: Rainer Joswig provided a helpful reference for `alexandria:setp` above. But I had some difficulty tracking down SBCL's implementation of `adjoin` in the source code, as it bottoms out in the internal op `%adjoin`. And, yes, I confess sometimes "I want to believe" that SBCL can work magic, like it's from some kind of advanced civilization.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick follow-up to the original post regarding SBCL `adjoin`. The source code in `list.lisp` at https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/tree/master/src/code provides the support macro `%adjoin` and the following description:

```
;;; %ADJOIN-*, %ASSOC-*, %MEMBER-*, and %RASSOC-* functions. Deftransforms
;;; delegate to TRANSFORM-LIST-PRED-SEEK and TRANSFORM-LIST-ITEM-SEEK which
;;; pick the appropriate versions. These win because they have only positional
;;; arguments, the TEST, TEST-NOT & KEY functions are known to exist (or not),
;;; and are known to be functions instead of function designators. We are also
;;; able to transform many common cases to -EQ versions, which are
;;; substantially faster then EQL using ones.
```

As ignis volens mentions above, the implementation is lists all the way down, even though there are some special transformations.